# Sort by any of 3 time fields

Tags: linq, sorting, datetime, null-coalescing-operator

A twofold question if I may. A record has 1-3 of an Arrive, Depart, and Pass fields specified. I want the results sorted by any of the times regardless of which actual column they came from. The query below sorts everything by passing time first from 00:00 to 23:59, then departure time from 00:00 to 23:50, then arrival time from 00:00 to 23:59. In other words I get three "blocks" of records, whereas I want something like this:

```
            Arr  Dep   Pass
1st result       00:01
2nd result 00:02
3rd result             00:03
4th result       23:58
5th result 23:59
```

etc.

The second part of the problem is the three fields are all nullable, and I need just the time portion of the DateTime? field. The date portion is undefined and potentially psuedo-random. If I take the Value.TimeOfDay of a null field then I'll get an AV. The coalescing operator would work on field.Value but it tales field.Value rather than field.Value.TimeOfDay which is the portion of the DateTime that I need.

So, please can you help fix my query to sort on non-null time portions of DateTime? Thanks.

Part of query:

```
        var results = from sl in db.WttScheduleLocations
                      orderby sl.Arrive.Value.TimeOfDay, sl.Depart.Value.TimeOfDay, sl.Pass.Value.TimeOfDay
                      select sl;
```

Part of model:

```
public class WttScheduleLocation
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Arrive { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Depart { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Pass { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: As is always the way with SO, puzzling for hours before posting, I think I cobbled together a solution. let b = sl.Arrive ?? sl.Depart ?? sl.Pass
 let c = DbFunctions.CreateTime(b.Value.Hour, b.Value.Minute, b.Value.Second) orderby c. I don't know how efficient that is though.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

```
var results = from sl in db.WttScheduleLocations
    orderby sl.Arrive.HasValue??sl.Arrive.Value.TimeOfDay descending
    orderby sl.Depart.HasValue??sl.Depart.Value.TimeOfDay descending
    orderby sl.Pass.HasValue??sl.Pass.Value.TimeOfDay descending
                      select sl;
```